# Regeneration while dying in 4th edition

Tags: dnd-4e

I recently started DMing after playing 4th edition D&D around 10-15 times. While going over player and DM books I started to wonder if regeneration works while a PC is dying.

For example, a level 2 fighter by the name of Korgul is down to -2 hit points. In the previous round he used Boundless Endurance. Since his modifier for the skill gives +2, that is a regeneration of +4. This would mean that he would get to 2 hit points at the start of his round and become conscious? Or does the regeneration stop?

Well this turned into to 2 questions actually. First one is about regeneration and dying in general.
Does dying count as bloodied in relation to Boundless Endurance.

To me, as a DM, if regeneration worked while dying it would seem overpowered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Though you are bloodied when at 0 or less HP, you do not regenerate.

From the glossary entry for Regeneration <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=161)</sup>:

> **Heal Each Turn:** If a creature has regeneration *and at least 1 hit point*, it regains a   specified number of hit points at the start of its turn. However, if its current hit point  total is 0 or lower, it does not regain hit points through regeneration.

From the Hit Points entry <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=159)</sup>:

> **Bloodied Value:** The bloodied value of a typical creature equals one-half its maximum hit points. A creature is bloodied when its current hit points drop to its bloodied value or lower. Certain powers and effects work only against a bloodied target or work better against such a target.
>
> **Dying:** When a character’s current hit points drop to 0 or lower, the character is dying.

Also, dropping to 0 or less HP ends a Stance <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=84)</sup>, such as Boundless Endurance:

> **[Stance] Duration:** A stance lasts until the character assumes another stance *or until the character falls unconscious or dies*.

Comment: Glad to help! Welcome! Keep up the good questions!

Comment: Huh so is "dies" synonymous with "dying"? I would expect them to be different states.

Comment: @tacroy No. When you drop to 0 HP, you are dying, and that includes entering the Unconscious state. You die if miss three savings throws, take additional damage totaling your bloodied value, or are the subject of a Coup De Grace.