# Ongoing damage while dying in 4th edition

Tags: dnd-4e

Similar to [Regeneration while dying in 4th edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18876/regeneration-while-dying-in-4th-edition), does a character continue to take ongoing damage when dropping to 0 hp?

Also, does he continue to make saving throws for all effects while dying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a dying character still takes ongoing damage at the start of their turn and can make saving throws to end ongoing damage and other effects that allow a save at the end of their turn. They also get their death saving throw, of course. (*Rules Compendium, page 224.*)